# Total moment around the centroid of an inverted pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

Why are both forces generate negative moments around the centroid of the pendulum in the following free body diagram? Shouldn't P generate a positive moment?

[image]

Comment: You're right that the torque supplied by $P$ about the pendulum's COM is opposite that by $N$. Which of these is "positive" and which is "negative" depends on the choice of coordinates. From the second equation, it appears that the book has chosen to call torques out of the plane of the page positive. (Notice that $\theta \in (\pi/2, \pi)$, so $\cos\theta < 0$. This makes $-Nl\cos\theta > 0$.)

Comment: thank you! I wasn't considering that theta is larger than 90 degrees